# upgrate iginte to 2.15 or Gridgain 8.9 Community Edition

Tags: ignite

I have a ignite cluster which is running 5 nodes in ignite 2.14, now I want to upgrade our cluster to newest version, so, should I upgrade to ignite 2.15 or Gridgain CE 8.9? Do you have any experience about this? are there any problem when migrate into newest ignite version?